# Height of child div (contains iframe) - resposive problem

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design

I have quite simply code and i've spent a day for solving problem, but still no progress :/ I want to display iframe with background-image. Snippet code is not showing background-image, so You can see live demo here: http://lukdan2.47.pl/index2.php

```css
.parrent {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://lukdan2.47.pl/images/black-iphone-frame.png');
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 427px;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 73%;
  padding-top: 37%;
}

iframe {
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child">
    <iframe src="http://sshtest.co.pl/" id="iphone-x-portrait"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

As You can see iframe has too much height. I can add

```css
.child {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 73%;
    padding-top: 37%;
    height: 550px;
    padding-bottom: 37%;
}
```

and it works fine.

But, for screen lower than 460px parent div is getting smaller so static height for child is not working correctly.

I've tried to change parent div to display flex and table (and change child div also) but nothing found that will solve my problem.

Help, please.

Comment: So you're trying to make the iframe responsive?

Comment: Anton Rusak. Yes. And i think it's very close. Width is working fine on RWD, but i have problem with height.

Comment: Still not clear to me. You want that iphone thing to fit into a small browser window?

Comment: Anton - please take a look here: http://lukdan2.47.pl/index2.php. It's working fine. But when You will change screen size and set f.e. 400px width You will see that iphone image is getting smaller (that's ok) but child div with iframe has too big height and it's outfit the iphone image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found solution.

```css
.iframe-container {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('http://lukdan2.47.pl/images/black-iphone-frame.png');
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

 
.iframe-container iframe {
border: 0;
height: 62%;
left: 40%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 20%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top: 11%;
padding-bottom: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="http://sshtest.co.pl/"></iframe>
</div>
```